# [01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/easysoft/oracle/InstantClient112/lib/libsqora.so' : file not found

Tags: linux, oracle, unixodbc, oracleclient

I am trying to acces oracle from linux server. I am using unixODBC.

When i try to acces oracle using isql and i get error that driver manager can't open libsqora.so.12.1.

odbc.ini

```
[NAME]
 Application Attributes = T
 Attributes = W
 BatchAutocommitMode = IfAllSuccessful
 BindAsFLOAT = F
 CloseCursor = F
 DisableDPM = F
 DisableMTS = T
 Driver = Oracle 11g ODBC driver
 DSN = DSN_NAME
 EXECSchemaOpt =
 EXECSyntax = T
 Failover = T
 FailoverDelay = 10
 FailoverRetryCount = 10
 FetchBufferSize = 64000
 ForceWCHAR = F
 Lobs = T
 Longs = T
 MaxLargeData = 0
 MetadataIdDefault = F
 QueryTimeout = T
 ResultSets = T
 ServerName = ServerName
 SQLGetData extensions = F
 Translation DLL =
 Translation Option = 0
 DisableRULEHint = T
 UserID = xxxx
 Password=<password>
 StatementCache=F
 CacheBufferSize=20
 UseOCIDescribeAny=F
```

odbcinst.ini

```
 [Oracle 11g ODBC driver]
 Description=Oracle ODBC driver for Oracle 11g
 Driver=/usr/local/easysoft/oracle/InstantClient112/lib/libsqora.so
 FileUsage=1
```

Then, when i use isql to acces oracle i get the following error:

```
 [root@xxxxx lib]# isql -v NAME
 [01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/easysoft/oracle/InstantClient112/lib/libsqora.so' : file not found
 [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

I had typo in odbcinst.ini.  I have corrected but still same error.

```
 [root@xxxxx tmp]# isql -v NAME
 [01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/easysoft/oracle/InstantClient112/lib/libsqora.so.11.1' : file not found
 [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect


 [root@xxxxx tmp]# ls -l /usr/local/easysoft/oracle/InstantClient112/lib/libsqora.so.11.1
 -rw-r--r-- 1 bin bin 996363 Sep  5  2010 /usr/local/easysoft/oracle/InstantClient112/lib/libsqora.so.11.1

 [Oracle 11g ODBC driver]
  Description=Oracle ODBC driver for Oracle 11g
  Driver=/usr/local/easysoft/oracle/InstantClient112/lib/libsqora.so.11.1
  FileUsage=1
```

ENV

```
 [root@xxxxx tmp]# env
 HOSTNAME=xxxxx
 SSH2_TTY=/dev/pts/0
 SHELL=/bin/bash
 TERM=xterm
 HISTSIZE=1000
 ODBC_DIR=/usr/local/easysoft/unixODBC
 OLDPWD=/usr/local/easysoft
 SSH_SESSION_ID=1424
 SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/easysoft/lib:/usr/local/easysoft/unixODBC/lib
 A__z="*SHLVL
 TNS_ADMIN=/usr/local/easysoft/oracle/InstantClient112/network/
 INPUTRC=/etc/inputrc
 PWD=/tmp
 LANG=en_US.UTF-8
 ODBCSYSINI=/etc/
 HOME=/root
 SHLVL=3
 ODBCINI=/etc
 LESSOPEN=|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
 ORACLE_HOME=/usr/local/easysoft/oracle/InstantClient112/
 G_BROKEN_FILENAMES=1
 _=/bin/env

 PATH=/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/easysoft/unixODBC/bin:/opt/oraClient/11.2.0.4/bin
```

Fixed original issue with LD_LIBRARY_PATH updates but now it is broken again since I am trying to use the 32bit Oracle client.

Installed 32bit oracle client in directory /opt/oraClient/11.2.0.4_32/.

Modified the odbcinst.ini:

```
[Oracle 11g ODBC driver]
Description=Oracle ODBC driver for Oracle 11g
#Driver=/usr/local/easysoft/oracle/InstantClient112/lib/libsqora.so.11.1
Driver=/opt/oraClient/11.2.0.4_32/lib/libsqora.so.11.1
FileUsage=1
```

Error:

```
[root@xxxxx lib]# /usr/local/bin/isql -v NAME                                                      
 [01000][unixODBC]  [Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/oraClient/11.2.0.4_32/lib/libsqora.so.11.1' : file not found
 [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

If I need to use the 32bit Oracle client, what am i doing wrong...I know it is something in environmental variables.

```
 [root@xxxxx lib]# file /opt/oraClient/11.2.0.4_32/lib/libsqora.so.11.1
 /opt/oraClient/11.2.0.4_32/lib/libsqora.so.11.1: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

I enable trace but am not able to attach document here.  I can email.

More debug info:

```
 [root@xxxxx bin]# ldd /opt/oraClient/11.2.0.4_32/lib/libsqora.so.11.1
 ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `/opt/oraClient/11.2.0.4_32/lib/libsqora.so.11.1'
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xffffe000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xf7f2b000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xf7f02000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7ee8000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/libnsl.so.1 (0xf7ecf000)
    libclntsh.so.11.1 => not found
    libodbcinst.so.1 => not found
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf7d71000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00134000)
```

I don't get one the "not found" which may be causing some problems:

```
 [root@xxxxx bin]# ls /opt/oraClient/11.2.0.4_32/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1
 /opt/oraClient/11.2.0.4_32/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1
```

Below is the most recent env output:

```
 [root@xxxxx]# env
  HOSTNAME=xxxxx
  SSH2_TTY=/dev/pts/0
  TERM=xterm
  SHELL=/bin/bash
  HISTSIZE=1000
  ODBC_DIR=/usr/local/easysoft/unixODBC
  SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
        LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oraClient/11.2.0.4_32/:/opt/oraClient/11.2.0.4_32/lib/:/usr/local/easysoft/oracle/InstantClient112:/usr/local/easysoft/oracle/InstantClient112/lib/
  TNS_ADMIN=/opt/oraClient/11.2.0.4_32/network/
  PATH=/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/easysoft/unixODBC/bin:/opt/oraClient/11.2.0.4_32/bin
  INPUTRC=/etc/inputrc
  LANG=en_US.UTF-8
  ODBCSYSINI=/etc/
  SHLVL=4
  HOME=/root
  ODBCINI=/etc
  ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oraClient/11.2.0.4_32/
  G_BROKEN_FILENAMES=1
  _=/bin/env
```

Comment: The base instant client doesn't have that file (or a `lib` directory). So is it really the instant client as the path suggests, or a full client (or server)?

Comment: Fixed...still not working.

Comment: If you've rearranged the instant client files, I don't know if that might be confusing internals links - perhaps the error is abput another that one then can't find? You might also need to add the `lib` directory (and/or its parent) to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, does that make any difference?

Comment: I updated the LD_LIBRARY_PATH with your feedback and it worked.

Comment: I got isql working but found out that the the application that i am building this for only supports 32bit oracle client. Therefore I installed 32bit oracle and have broken it again. I am getting the same error now when executing sql.

Answer (score 50):

This error is misleading:

```
The file that the error claimed was not present did exist.
```

I was able to chase down the actual missing file by executing:

```
# ldd /path/to/your/socalled/missing/file.so
```

This returned a series of files and one said:

```
libodbcinst.so.2 => not found
```

That is was the culprit for me.  I then created the link that I needed and voila, the error went away.

ref: http://mailman.unixodbc.org/pipermail/unixodbc-support/2011-November/003018.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip, had the same missing file problem when setting up Linux I Application access on Ubuntu.

Comment: If the file is present but not in the library path, you can set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or add a file to `/etc/ld/conf.d` and rerun `ldconfig`

Comment: @user3771500 Can you pls post which links you created, I'm missing these files: libicuuc.so.42 and libicudata.so.42

Comment: # ldd saved me!

Comment: I'd like to know how you "created the link" as well? On my side I have `libclntsh.so.12.1 => not found` and `libclntshcore.so.12.1 => not found`

Answer (score 3):

Instant client doesn't have a `lib` directory. If you've downloaded the [`instantclient-odbc-linux` package](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html) and unzipped that in the same location as the basic package then the `libsqora.so.11.1` file will be durectly under `/usr/local/easysoft/oracle/InstantClient112`.

So your .ini should point to:

```
Driver=/usr/local/easysoft/oracle/InstantClient112/libsqora.so.11.1
```

Note the extension though; you might want to soft-link that to `libsqora.so`. If you've moved the `.so` files into a subdirectory after unzipping (?) then you'd need:

```
Driver=/usr/local/easysoft/oracle/InstantClient112/lib/libsqora.so.11.1
```

---

It looks like you've reoriganised the instant client files after unzipping, creating a `lib` directory. I'm not sure if that will directly cause you problems. But you also haven't set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, as the [installation instructions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html) suggest:

> **Installation Steps:**
>
> 1. Download the appropriate Instant Client packages for your platform. All installations REQUIRE the Basic package.
> 2. Unzip the packages into a single directory such as "instantclient".
> 3. Set the library loading path in your environment to the directory in Step 2 ("instantclient"). On many UNIX platforms, LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>      is the appropriate environment variable. On Windows, PATH should be
>      used.
> 4. Start your application and enjoy.

Clearly step (4) isn't working for you yet, but I think that's because you haven't done step (3); and I think as you've split the files - which might itself cause an issue - you may need to include both `.../InstantClient112` and `.../InstantClient112/lib` in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable. And make sure the modified value is exported. I'm not sure why you'd want to rearrange the files though.

Comment: This is company pacakged build for unixODBC and looks like they included the oracle driver and instantclient.  But i am pointing the driver to the 32bit oracle installation under  /opt/oraClient/11.2.0.4_32/.

Comment: Please help...I have tried every alteration to the odbsinst.ini file.

Comment: @user3521305 - if you're now getting ORA-01017, that isn't a driver or environment problem. You're successfully contacting a database, but whether it's the right one depends on where your `SMARTS_SDI_NA` DSN is pointing. That is the wrong DB instance, or the username or password in your `odbc.ini` are wrong for that DSN. Remember those are case-sensitive in 11g. One of those three must be wrong, I think, most likely the password. Check you can connect with a different client.

Comment: I pasted the wrong output...the ORA-01017 is for the working one with the 64bit oracle driver...I can get that to work.  My problem is when i try to use the 32bit oracle driver.

Comment: OK, then that file definitely exists - you got the 32-bit ODBC package - and you set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to that new location?

Comment: Yes. I installed the 32bit Oracle client and set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  Detail of the contents are above.

Comment: @user3521305 - the `not found` still suggests `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` isn't set, or isn't exported.

Comment: I pasted the latest env output above...As you can see I have set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  I think it has something to do with something to do with a missing file pointer for 32bit odbc driver.

Comment: The only thing i can think of is to install the 32bit Oracle client and driver again from Oracle site.  The one I am using right now is a packaged version from my company but it was tested by them so hard to believe it would be broken.

Comment: @user3521305 - it's set, but are you sure it's exported? That's the only think I can think of that would cause this behaviour.

Comment: It wouldn't be in env output if it wasn't exported.  Is there someone with more experience that could troubleshoot via debug?

Comment: @user3521305 - yes it would. It wouldn't be in the output of `export` if it wasn't exported. Having both Oracle versions in it is confusing but it'll use the first match so shouldn't matter here. The file exists where you expect, the only reason for `ldd` not to be able to see it is that variable not being set/exported properly, in my experience anyway. Good luck.

Comment: Is someone esle from support going to pick this up or is there no more help coming?

Answer (score -5):

`sudo apt-get install libaio1 libaio-dev`