# File Not Found PDO SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

I am getting the following error when trying to connect to a SQL Server via PHP:
database connect error：SQLSTATE[01000]: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.2.so.0.1' : file not found

I have verified the file really does exist via

```
ls -l /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.2.so.0.1
```

which yields

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17306000 Jul  3 06:34 /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.2.so.0.1
```

My connection code is:

```
$dns="sqlsrv:Server=192.168.X.X;Database=999";

try
{
    $mspdo = new PDO($dns, "user", "password");
}
catch(PDOException $pe)
{
     die("database connect error：". $pe->getMessage());
}
```

I'm at a loss.

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24388244/1301076

Comment: That did resolve the missing file error.  However, it is now telling me that Microsoft requires libssl 1.0.0.  I am running 1.1.0.  Is there any way around that or some other way I can connect to a SQL Server in PHP 7?